# PSQLException: ERROR: insert or update on table "*" violates foreign key constraint

Tags: java, postgresql, jpa, jdbc, glassfish

I try to insert all data from one database to another one. These two databases have the same structure (they use the same Entities). I use PostgreSQL 9.1, Glassfish 4.0, EclipseLink (JPA 2.1) and Java EE 7 Web.

These are the entities:

```
@Entity
public class Store extends BaseEntity {

    @NotNull
    private String name;

   /*
    * required
    */
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    private List<Price> listPrices;

   /*
    * required
    */
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    private List<BusinessHours> listBusinessHours;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST, optional = false)
    private PointCoordinates pointCoordinates;
    ...
}
```

For example one of the @OneToMany annotated entities:

```
@Entity
public class BusinessHours extends BaseEntity {

    private Boolean holiday;

    ...
}
```

BaseEntity contains the Id with GenerationType.SEQUENCE and the serialVersionUID.

persistence.xml:

```
<persistence-unit name="restDBFromRawData" transaction-type="JTA">
    <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
    <jta-data-source>jdbc/RestDBFromRawData</jta-data-source>

    <class>info.mycompany.entities.BusinessHours</class>
    <class>info.mycompany.entities.Store</class>
    <class>info.mycompany.entities.PointCoordinates</class>
    <class>info.mycompany.entities.Price</class>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>true</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <properties>
      <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="drop-and-create-tables"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>

<persistence-unit name="restClientDB" transaction-type="JTA">
    <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
    <jta-data-source>jdbc/RestClientDB</jta-data-source>

    <class>info.mycompany.entities.BusinessHours</class>
    <class>info.mycompany.entities.Store</class>
    <class>info.mycompany.entities.PointCoordinates</class>
    <class>info.mycompany.entities.Price</class>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>true</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <properties>
      <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="drop-and-create-tables"/>
      <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation.output-mode" value="both"/>
    </properties>
   </persistence-unit>
```

If I try to get all the data from one database and try to insert them in the other database (addStoresToRestClientDB):

```
@Stateless
public class StoreOutputService {

    @EJB
    StoreOutputDAO storeOutputDAO;

    @EJB
    StoreOutputRestClientDAO storeOutputRCDAO;

    public List<Store> getAllStores() {
        return storeOutputDAO.findAll();
    }

    public void addStoresToRestDBFromRawData() {
        //this works fine
        ...
        for (Store store : listStore) {
            storeOutputDAO.edit(store);
        }
    }

    public void addStoresToRestClientDB() {

        List<Store> listStore = getAllStores();
        //size of list is right, the same like I insert in "addStoresToRestDBFromRawData"

        for (Store store : listStore) {
            storeOutputRCDAO.edit(store);
        }
    }
}
```

I get the following error:

```
WARNING:   Local Exception Stack: 
Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.0.v20130507-3faac2b): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: insert or update on table "store_businesshours" violates foreign key constraint "fk_store_businesshours_listbusinesshours_id"
  Detail: Key (listbusinesshours_id)=(55) is not present in table "businesshours".
Error Code: 0
Call: INSERT INTO STORE_BUSINESSHOURS (listBusinessHours_ID, Store_ID) VALUES (?, ?)
    bind => [2 parameters bound]
Query: DataModifyQuery(name="listBusinessHours" sql="INSERT INTO STORE_BUSINESSHOURS (listBusinessHours_ID, Store_ID) VALUES (?, ?)")
...
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: insert or update on table "store_businesshours" violates foreign key constraint "fk_store_businesshours_listbusinesshours_id"
  Detail: Key (listbusinesshours_id)=(55) is not present in table "businesshours".
...
WARNING:   StandardWrapperValve[info.mycompany.web.ApplicationConfig]: Servlet.service() for servlet info.mycompany.web.ApplicationConfig threw exception
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: insert or update on table "store_businesshours" violates foreign key constraint "fk_store_businesshours_listbusinesshours_id"
  Detail: Key (listbusinesshours_id)=(55) is not present in table "businesshours".
```

The DAOs should be fine. `StoreOutputDAO` uses the Persistence Unit `restDBFromRawData` and `StoreOutputRestClientDAO` uses the Persistence Unit `restClientDB`.

The JDBC `jdbc/RestDBFromRawData` uses a connection pool with a `javax.sql.ConnectionPoolDataSource` ressourcetype (classname: org.postgresql.ds.PGConnectionPoolDataSource) and the other JDBC "jdbc/RestClientDB" uses "javax.sql.XADataSource" ressourcetype (classname: org.postgresql.xa.PGXADataSource). If I take the same configuration in "jdbc/RestClientDB" like in "jdbc/RestDBFromRawData", I get the following error message: "Local transaction already has 1 non-XA Resource".

`$GLASSFISH_HOME/glassfish/lib` and `$GLASSFISH_HOME/domains/domain1/lib` contains the PostgreSQL driver "postgresql-9.1-901.jdbc4.jar.

If I take a look with pgAdmin in the databases everything looks fine. They have the same structure and everything else works fine: inserting datas in another database and inserting datas with `StoreOutputDAO` except `StoreOutputRestClientDAO`.

**Update**
BaseEntity:

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class BaseEntity implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    private int id;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The error occurs because the business hour is not present in the other database.  Make sure you insert it.

Do you call persist on it, how is its Id defined?  You might need to null out its Id and version when migrating it to the other database.

Comment: To your first sentence: but this is why I annotated BusinessHours with  "(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)". To your second sentence: I updated my post and added the BaseEntity, this is how the Id is defined. How can I null its Id out?